# Can I delete libdrm.so files?

Tags: 12.10, system

In my Ubuntu 12.10 /usr/lib/ folder, there are some files like `libdrm.so.2.4.0`, `libdrm.so.2` . What are they used for?  Can I delete them ? [image: file icons]

Comment: Why do you feel the need to consider deleting these files?

Comment: since I installed libdrm, mesa to recegnize my graphics in ubuntu12.10, then I found that after installation, the cpu fan caused lots of noise. Then I wanted to remove libdrm and mesa. So I wonder whether these files were installed by libdrm.

Answer (score 3):

> **libdrm**
>
> This library implements the userspace interface to the kernel DRM services. DRM stands for "Direct Rendering Manager", which is the kernelspace portion of the "Direct Rendering Infrastructure" (DRI). The DRI is currently used on Linux to provide hardware-accelerated OpenGL drivers.

So I would assume... no, unless you want to research if they are used somewhere. They are "**s** hared **o** bject" files. You can use `ldd` to see if they are linked.

---

From [dobey](https://askubuntu.com/users/50737/dobey) in comment:

The ones which are for drivers that are not needed for video display on the system can be removed, but they should be removed by `apt-get` remove on the package containing them, not simple `rm` of the files.

Comment: The ones which for are drivers that aren't needed for video display on the system can be removed, but they should be removed by `apt-get remove` on the package containing them, not simple `rm` of the files.

Comment: Go ahead, and feel free to recommend my comments for deletion after. That's why I said it, instead of providing another answer. :)